# undefined reference to 'gnutls_...' functions

Tags: c, encryption, linker, cryptography, gnutls

So for an assignment I need to use GnuTLS. I have downloaded gnutls by following this guide http://www.bauer-power.net/2014/06/how-to-install-gnutls-3123-from-source.html

However, using any of the gnutls functions, similar to how they are used in the official gnutls documentation (http://www.gnutls.org/manual/html_node/Client-examples.html), displays several errors after building. All errors follow this format:

`...pathtofile:line#/..undefined reference to 'gnutls_...'`

I understand that this might be a linking problem, however I am quite new to this type of environment. What should I do? I have tried to install gnutls again several times.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04, gnutls-3.1.23 and eclipse Luna.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have an error on your link line.

Add the flag `-lgnutls` to the `ld` command (or, if just one C file, the compile line).

Comment: I've managed, thanks alot. 

For anyone who is slightly unfamiliar and wish to use eclipse for building:
1)goto project->properties->c/c++ build -> Settings->Tool Settings->GCC C Linker->Linraries and under -l write gnutls

2)in Miscellaneous (right under Libraries), fill in Linker flags with `pkg-config gnutls --cflags --libs`   

(include `)